# Getting stats for Twitter app

Tags: twitter, statistics, oauth

I'm using Twitter's OAuth for my app (DroidIn) 
To my dismay I can't find any way to track who and how often is using the app. Searching Twitter for "sent from DroidIn" does not yield any results. I suppose I can call some sort of counter app from my code but that doesn't seem to be fair to my users. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that yet again I have to answer my own question. After some investigation and feedback from question posted on Google Twitter developer group it seems that for now there are no stats easily accessible or available. Said that I found 2 interesting things:

1. You can search Twitter using source:yourapp switch. For example you can try this query

   android source:API
2. There is very exciting streaming API from Twitter. I have a [short write-up](http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/31/spritzer-your-twitter/) in my dev blog.

But if you want some actual stats there's no other choice today but implement it as part of your app. There's one more possibility if you have some sort of web-based interface you may want to use Google Analytics to trigger some Google javascript while submitting the update. I'm trying that right now and may end up with article in the blog